# Unable to open project folder in localhost

Tags: apache-http-server, lamp

Running lamp.

When I am opening a particular project folder called eduwatch in localhost (other projects are working fine), I get the following error.

```
Internal Server Error

The server encountered an internal error or misconfiguration and was unable to complete your request.

Please contact the server administrator at webmaster@localhost to inform them of the time this error occurred, and the actions you performed just before this error.

More information about this error may be available in the server error log.
Apache/2.4.25 (Debian) Server at localhost Port 80
```

I went ahead and checked the Apache log and found this,

```
::1 - - [23/Apr/2019:08:56:44 +0530] "GET /eduwatch/ HTTP/1.1" 500 799 "http://localhost/" "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64; rv:66.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/66.0"
```

Here is the log of another working project directory called bl, just to compare. 799 vs 521.

```
::1 - - [23/Apr/2019:09:00:16 +0530] "GET /bl/ HTTP/1.1" 200 521 "http://localhost/" "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64; rv:66.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/66.0"
```

I am unable to deduce anything from this log. Can anyone help?

Comment: The simple answer is likely that the website itself is using a script that isn't being processed correctly.

Comment: Did you have a `.htaccess` file in that directory...?

Comment: Oh yes, I resolved it. .htaccess had some comments checked. I just had to uncheck it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had this line in .htaccess checked.

```
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://***********/$1 [R,L]
```

I just had to uncheck it and it worked fine.